# Google Play In-App Review API: How often does it show the dialog roughly?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-core

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) states on a topic when to ask for a review:

> Trigger the in-app review flow after a user has experienced enough of
> your app or game to provide useful feedback.

> Do not prompt the user excessively for a review. This approach helps
> minimize user frustration and limit API usage (see the section on
> quotas).

But that's very vague, can we trigger it quite often (like after every level in a game) or should we add some wait periods inside the app (like after every level but minimum wait time a month)?

There is a similar API on iOS and it's observed that the popup shows "about three times a year". It would be helpful to know similar rough estimate, it would help to design right usage of the API and remove unnecessary user frustration.

Comment: `can we trigger it quite often (like after every level in a game)` sounds like you really like getting negative reviews...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The API has a quota, so if the quota is similar as on iOS (allows the dialog about three times a year), we could trigger it often and let the API handle it. If it allows the dialog more often (like every week), we have to implement custom logic to avoid negative reviews. The question is if the custom logic is needed.

Comment: While this is an implementation detailed and the exact quota is subject to change, we have updated the docs to clarify it a bit better https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#quotas

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no response as to whether the user rated your app or the rating dialog was shown through the In-App Review API itself. But you get these guarantees:

- If the app already has been reviewed by a user, they won't be prompted to review the app again.
- You can test without quota by testing against Internal App Sharing or the Internal Test Track.

In case you are concerned that you might display the dialog too often, we recommend remembering when you last called `launchReviewFlow` locally in a persistent way.

Let's go with your example of calling `launchReviewFlow` after every level:

- Depending on the size of a level this might be too much
- You won't know whether the dialog has been displayed
- Once the user rates your app the dialog won't show again

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#troubleshooting)

Comment: Is there any way to check/listen whether a user-submitted review or cancelled/dismissed/Not-Now??

Comment: No. This is not an intended feature of the library.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer Is it documented that prompt won't be shown if user has reviewed the app once? Couldn't find it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

Comment: @keyboardsurfer suppose I have selected a positive flow for which I am going to show in app review. If some user rates the app at this time, what would happen if same situation (positive flow ) has happened after some long time (quota has been restored).

Comment: If the user has already rated the app(by going to the app page in the play store) and if i try to show that particular user "in-app" review dialog, will it appear or not?

Comment: It won't. Mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#troubleshooting
"The user has already reviewed the app."

Comment: This makes a lot stuff easier. I was struggling with doing and saving stuff in DataStore..

Answer (score 0):

Google Review Dialog API

API Version

> implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'

Their is flag via which we can know that Dialog is open/shown or not i have used it and it is working , this is the key "isNoOp" when it is false then dialog is visible and in case of true dialog is not visible ,

```
 private fun askForReview() {
        val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
        manager.requestReviewFlow().addOnCompleteListener { request ->
            if (request.isSuccessful) {
                val reviewInfo = request.result
                logWarning("isSuccessful Result ${reviewInfo.toString()}")

                manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
                    .addOnFailureListener {

                        logWarning("addOnFailureListener  data = ${it.fillInStackTrace()}")
                        logWarning("addOnFailureListener, reason=$it")

                    }.addOnCompleteListener {

                        logWarning("addOnCompleteListener isComplete = ${it.isComplete} - isSuccessful= ${it.isSuccessful}")
                        logWarning("addOnCompleteListener it = ${it.toString()}")
                        logWarning("addOnCompleteListener result = ${it.result.toString()}")
                        logWarning("addOnCompleteListener exception = ${it.exception.toString()}")

                        val isNoOp = reviewInfo.toString().substring(reviewInfo.toString().indexOf("isNoOp")+7,reviewInfo.toString().length-1)

                        logWarning("addOnCompleteListener data.isNoOp = $isNoOp")


                    }.addOnSuccessListener {
                        logWarning("addOnSuccessListener ${it.toString()}")
                    }

            } else {
                logWarning("isSuccessful == false")
                logWarning("In-app review request failed, reason=${request.exception}")
            }
        }
    }
    fun logWarning(logs:String?){
        if (logs != null) {
            Log.e("googlereview",logs)
        }
    }
```